# Как парсить данные в несколько потоков?

Tags: c#, selenium, chromedriver

Есть chromedriver. Я хочу запустить его в 3 потока и слать данные этим инстансам из списка. Как лучше всего реализовать это? Нужно понять как определить свободный инстанс

Comment: Конвертируете список в очередь. В методе получаете из очереди элемент пока очередь не пуста

Comment: А этот метод запускаете в пуле потоков